# How to use OMPL for path planning

Tags: ros, navigation, ompl, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a PGM/YAML set map that was generated from a Hokuyo LIDAR with an iRobot Create, and the objective is to use OMPL's libraries for motion planning in this map. I have the OMPL GUI, but there seems to be no straightforward way to use user generated maps, and all the example maps are in .dae format. ROS tutorials always seemed to talk about PR2 arm navigation.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to how I can start off using OMPL's algorithms for navigation in my own map. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61316/how-to-use-ompl-for-path-planning/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could take a look into [moveit](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/MoveIt!). It uses OMPL to do the path planning and is pretty simple to use. Even though I am not sure that a LIDAR will work as a sensor, there are different sensor types accepted

Kai

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1